# find text in file and then when found take the word on same line and insert into code

Tags: bash, grep

i want to insert the first word from file.txt when it matches string in my documents, i have like 500 documents like this so it would be nice if it works

file.txt looks like this:

```
test1 t1
test2 t2
test3 t3
```

this is my code

```
code="t1"

sed -i -e 's/^/Name="$code" /'
```

this will result in

```
code="t1"

sed -i -e 's/^/Name="t1" /'
```

this what i want for final output in all my documents:

document1.txt

```
code="t1"

sed -i -e 's/^/Name="test1" /'
```

document2.txt

```
code="t2"

sed -i -e 's/^/Name="test2" /'
```

Comment: I feel like you're telling us **how** you think you need to do something but not **what** it is you need to do. You have a file named `file.txt` that's never mentioned again and then you have assignments like `code="t1"` and then a sed script that attempts to use `"$code"` but you don't show us what the input to that sed script looks like (or is that what `file.txt` is?), nor do you show us what the output should look like, nor do you tell us what part in all of this `file.txt` plays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't clearly understand your requirement. If you cant to extract the first word depending on the second word and then do some string manipulation, following might help.

`file.txt` content:

```
test1 t1
test2 t2
test3 t3
```

Extract first word, given the second word:

```
second="t1"                                       # change this for a different match
first=$(sed -n "s/\(.*\) $second/\1/p" file.txt)  # now $first is "test1"
echo "first word is ${first} and blah..."         # write it to a file or do anything you need here
```

Comment: when i put like this sed -i -e 's/^/Name="$first" /' i get output in my document as $first

Comment: Single quotes do not allow variable expansion. Try this instead, `sed -i -e "s/^/Name=$first/" `

Comment: thanks that works but then my other script wont work, sed -i -e "s/^/Name=$first/" should be added first to every line with a space after too in my other document, so output will be Name="test1"+space here

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understood the requirement. Why can't you add the space at the end: `sed -i -e "s/^/Name=$first /"`

Comment: Output needs to be "test1" with quotes!

Comment: It works as expected but without the quotes but I need them hehe, Name="test1"+space should be final output

Comment: `sed -i -e 's/^/Name="'"$first"'" /'` is the syntax you're looking for above (don't enclose a whole script in double quotes as that exposes the whole script to the shell for parsing, enclose the script in single quotes as always and then use single quotes again to break out of it just long enough to expose the minimal section necessary to the shell, e.g. to expand a variable) but it's still extremely unclear what it is you're really trying to do.